# Adapting Flask Login to GCP; "is_authenticated" is not being set on login

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, flask-login

I'm using this package:
https://github.com/anchitarnav/flask-login-gcp-datastore
... to use the GCP Datastore (instead of a SQL database).

I'm able to add users but when I login the 'is_authenticated' property is always false. I'm not yet understanding how 'is_authenticated' is being set within the flask_login code. Perhaps someone who knows more about flask_login could provide some insight.

This post ([Flask Login login_user not setting is_authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090236/flask-login-login-user-not-setting-is-authenticated)) suggests that one should add an 'authenticated' field to the User model but that doesn't seem right to me. Seems that flask_login should normally set the 'is_authenticated' property.

It's also possible that I'm not using the flask-login-gcp-datastore package correctly. The documentation is slim.

This is part of an effort to upgrade from Python2 to Python3 on App Engine.

Thank you

---

Here's my code:

****init**.py**

```
from flask import Flask
##from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager

# init SQLAlchemy so we can use it later in our models
##db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret-key-goes-here'
    ##app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
    ##db.init_app(app)

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    from .project.models import User

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        # since the user_id is just the primary key of our user table, use it in the query for the user
        ##return User.query.get(int(user_id))
        print("before get user")
        u = User.get(int(user_id))
        print(u.is_authenticated)
        return u
        ##return User.get(int(user_id))

    from .project.auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

    from .project.main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    from .main import home_api as home_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(home_blueprint)

    from .eventSupport import events_api as events_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(events_blueprint)

    return app
```

**auth.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import login_user, current_user
from .models import ndb, User
client = ndb.Client()

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    template_values = {
        'user': 'Fred',
    }
    return render_template('login.html',**template_values)

@auth.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_post():
    # login code goes here
    email = request.form.get('email')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    remember = True if request.form.get('remember') else False

    ##user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    with client.context():
        query = ndb.gql("SELECT * FROM User WHERE email = :1", email)
        user = query.get()

    # check if the user actually exists
    # take the user-supplied password, hash it, and compare it to the hashed password in the database
    if not user or not check_password_hash(user.password, password):
        ##flash('Please check your login details and try again.')
        print('login failed')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login')) # if the user doesn't exist or password is wrong, reload the page

    print('before login')
    result = login_user(user, remember=remember)
    print(result)
    if not current_user.is_active:
        print("user not active")
    print(current_user.is_anonymous)
    print(current_user.get_id())
    return redirect(url_for('main.profile'))
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from flask_login import login_required, current_user
##from . import db

main = Blueprint('main', __name__,template_folder="templates")

@main.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

@main.route('/profile')
##@login_required
def profile():
    print("profile start")
    if not current_user.is_active:
        print("user is inactive")
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        print("user is not authenticated")
    if current_user.is_anonymous:
        print("user is anonymous")
    print(current_user.get_id())
    print("profile end")
    return render_template('profile.html',name=current_user.name)
```

**models.py**

```
from google.cloud import ndb
from google.cloud.ndb.context import get_context

from flask_login_user.gcp.datastore.config import get_db_client
from flask_login_user.gcp.datastore.caching import cached
from flask_login_user.gcp.datastore.user import User
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there's something wrong with the package. I scaled it back to use only the following:

```
from flask_login_user.gcp.datastore.config import get_db_client
class User(UserMixin,ndb.Model):
    """
    The User class that you are required to implement for flask-login
    https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class
    """
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    password = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

    def get_id(self):
        """
        returns a unicode that uniquely identifies this user,
        and can be used to load the user from the user_loader callback
        :return: str: user_id
        """
        return self.key.id()

    def get(user_id: str):
        """
        Get an object of User class based on the passed user_id. returns None if user not found
        :param user_id: str: The user ID for which the User object is required
        :return: User or None
        """
        present_context = get_context(raise_context_error=False)
        if present_context:
            return User.get_by_id(id=user_id)
        else:
            with get_db_client().context():
                return User.get_by_id(id=user_id)
```

... and it's now working normally -- 'is_authenticated' is being set as expected.